# Connect to Postgres running on docker with pyodbc

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, pyodbc

trying to connect to a Postgres database inside docker but having the following problem:

> File "", line 1, in  pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001',
>   '[08001] could not connect to server: No such file or directory\n\tIs
>   the server running locally and accepting\n\tconnections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?\n (101) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The connection is being established with the following:

```
conn_str = ("DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so;""DATABASE=mytestdb;""UID=postgres;""PWD=mysecretpassword""SERVER=localhost;""PORT=5432;");

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Comment: *trying to connect to a Postgres database inside docker* did the application that trying to connect inside a docker instance or on the host OS? also, on your connection string it says localhost (`SERVER=localhost`), you might want to see the ip of your docker instance, otherwise setup [a NAT for the docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)..

Comment: Thanks for this, I just checked that the container IP was 172.17.0.2 and changed it on the code but still got the same issue.

Comment: is the host had the same subnet address with that IP? something like 172.17.0.1? if you have pgAdmin, you may want to connect it first. also just a side note, do you have any third party anti virus or firewall? that can also be the cause your host unable to communicate with the docker instance.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure on your **docker** container you expose port 5432 other wise you wont be able to connect. This information can clear your thoughts. https://medium.com/@lvthillo/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7

on your docker-compose.yml change it to something like this:

```
db:
image: postgres
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

it can be 5432 or 5435 if you already have pg on your local machine.

Comment: I followed those steps (used that post as reference). I also changed the SERVER to SERVER=172.17.0.2 since that's the container IP but I still got the same error.

Comment: you need to change you config to allow remote address to connect. did you do that? also do not use IP simply use db or the name of your image.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is trying to connect postgres via unix socket file in host /tmp/ folder.

So configure mount point for docker container in posgres docker-compose file as below:

```
volumes:
      - /tmp:/var/lib/postgresql
```

then rebuild postgres container again.